# How to create Card using Angular material?

Tags: angular-material-5, angular-material-6

I'm new to Angular Material Here i have mention Image of What Actually i Need?
I don't how to split row in card
[image]

Comment: If you want to use MatCard with table format then look at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2yfhga-m2hgez?file=app/tab-group-custom-label-example.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this,

Here i tried angular material card,  [Click Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2yfhga?file=app/tab-group-custom-label-example.html) to see.

```
<mat-card class="example-card">


 <mat-card-content>

  <img mat-card-image src="https://image4.geekbuying.com/ggo_pic/2016-08-30/2016083001543551umb5a0d.jpg" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu" style="width:100px; float:left; height:100px">

  <mat-card-header>
   <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
    <mat-card-subtitle>Headphones</mat-card-subtitle>
    <mat-card-title>Xiaomi Redmi Note 4</mat-card-title>

   </mat-card-header>
  <br>
    <mat-card-header>
    <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
      <mat-card-title>$225</mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>


   </mat-card-content>

  </mat-card>
```

Comment: i single row it should print in three times in that case where i want to mention Row.

Comment: @Sudharsan Venkatraj Update your Question with your code, I'll try my best